How to position image side-by-side with text input using Bootstrap 5
I'm trying to position a magnifying glass image to the left side of a text input. It is being rendered above the text input. What is the right way to keep them side-by-side with Bootstrap 5?


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid mt-3" style="background-color: white;">
  <form method="GET" class="override-navbar-form col-sm-12" action="#">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5 mx-auto">
        <div class="text-black text-center">
          <label for="query_text"></label>
          <img style="max-height: 15px" src="/static/images/mag_glass.png" alt="">
          <input type="text" id="query_text" name="query_text" value="{{ query_text }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
          <br>
          <br>
          <button type="submit" class="search-button" style="margin-right: 5px" name="submit_type" value="search">Search</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>




Protip: Don't use line breaks for spacing. That's not their purpose. Use margin, padding, flex features, etc. Bootstrap has accommodations for all that.

Protip: Use CSS classes (either Bootstrap's or custom) for styles. Don't use inline styling, which makes your document more difficult to interpret and maintain.

Protip: You seem to be using empty columns to center your form. That's not the right approach, as extra markup constitutes technical debt. See the available flex alignment properties (or simply text alignment) instead.

There are at least three different ways to do this:

flex
the grid
input-group

Here is an example using each:


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container-fluid mt-3" style="background-color: white;">
  <form method="GET" class="override-navbar-form col-sm-12" action="#">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5 mx-auto">
        <div class="text-black text-center">
          <label for="query_text"></label>

          <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            <img style="max-height: 15px" src="https://placehold.co/15" alt="">
            <input type="text" id="query_text" name="query_text" value="I'm in a .d-flex" class="form-control ms-1" placeholder="Search...">
          </div>

          <div class="row gx-1 align-items-center">
            <div class="col-auto">
              <img style="max-height: 15px" src="https://placehold.co/15" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <input type="text" id="query_text" name="query_text" value="I'm in a .col in a .row" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><img style="max-height: 15px" src="https://placehold.co/15" alt=""></span>
            <input type="text" id="query_text" name="query_text" value="I'm in an .input-group" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
          </div>

          <br>
          <br>
          <button type="submit" class="search-button" style="margin-right: 5px" name="submit_type" value="search">Search</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>




The flex approach is working perfectly, thank you!
